# Python package not installing sub package requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x

How should I correctly structuring my python package so that when I install my package in development mode, it also installs the sub-packages along with the sub-package's dependency?

I have currently setup my package as below. When I install the package in development mode [pip install -e package], it only installs the requirements in the setup.py of the package and does not install the requirements of the sub-packages

```
package
 |-__init__.py
 |-setup.py
 |-sub-package-a
   |-__init__.py
   |-setup.py
 |-sub-package-b
   |-__init__.py
   |-setup.py
```